# Consume a WCF REST Service with webHttpBinding in Sharepoint 2010 WebPart

Tags: visual-web-part, wcf, rest

I have developed a custom WCF REST service with webHttpBinding in VS2010 and trying to consume in SharePoint 2010 WebPart developed in VS2010. I don't know how to do the settings. Please help!

Please See: Both the WCF REST service and SharePoint 2010 WebPart are part of one VS 2010 solution but are different projects.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CKS Dev](http://cksdev.codeplex.com/) to create WCF service in SharePoint. Following article can be used as a starting point to create WCF services in SharePoint.
http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.in/2011/03/sharepoint-2010-create-custom-wcf.html